# crash of msf4j microservice

Tags: java, jvm, wso2, msf4j

I have 1 microservice developed based on wso2 msf4j(on java)
This microservice runs very well when there is small amount of requests.
But after increasing the amount of requests, I saw it became crashed. 
I can't see anything in logs(the log4j mode is TRACE). I can guess this is memory problem, because the free memory in high amount of requests is very small ( 10Mb), but I am not sure that was the such reason for that crash.

Is there anyway to understand the exact reason of this issue ?

Comment: In all cases you should monitor the JVM (e.g. using the jconsole of the JDK). Indeed 10MB of free memory isn't very much mainly when using web services..

Comment: As @GabrielVince mentioned monitor memory usage using jconsole. If you experience any Out of memory issue, can you get a memory/heap dump and check?

Comment: @Thusitha is right, the parameters are XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError (and XX:HeapDumpPath=/tmp/dumpfile )